# How do I define a SQLAlchemy relation representing the latest object in a collection?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model with a one-to-many relationship between table `x` and table `y`. The record (if any) with the greatest `id` in table `y` where `y.x_id = x.id` is special. Class `X` and class `Y` map tables `x` and `y`.

I know how to define `X.all_y` (`ORDER BY y.id`). How do I define `X.latest_y` equivalent to `X.all_y[-1]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the purely relational way to do it requires using a subquery to get the "latest" or "max" value, correlated to the parent, then equating that with the members of the collection.  It means you'll get best results if you put an index on the column that determines "the latest":

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo='debug')

m = MetaData()

parent = Table('parent', m, 
                Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
)

child = Table('child', m, 
                Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id')),
                Column('sortkey', Integer)
                )

m.create_all(engine)

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.all_c = children

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, sortkey):
        self.sortkey = sortkey

latest_c = select([func.max(child.c.sortkey)]).\
                where(child.c.parent_id==parent.c.id).\
                correlate(parent).\
                as_scalar()

mapper(Parent, parent, properties={
    'all_c':relation(Child),
    'latest_c':relation(Child, 
                            primaryjoin=and_(
                                child.c.sortkey==latest_c, 
                                child.c.parent_id==parent.c.id
                            ),
                            uselist=False
    )
})

mapper(Child, child)

session = sessionmaker(engine)()

p1, p2, p3 = Parent([Child('a'), Child('b'), Child('c')]), \
                Parent([Child('b'), Child('c')]),\
                Parent([Child('f'), Child('g'), Child('c')])

session.add_all([p1, p2, p3])
session.commit()

assert p1.latest_c.sortkey == 'c'
assert p2.latest_c.sortkey == 'c'
assert p3.latest_c.sortkey == 'g'
```

Alternatively, you can on some platforms use LIMIT, which can produce faster results since you avoid the aggregation and can join the collection item on its primary key:

```
latest_c = select([child.c.id]).\
                where(child.c.parent_id==parent.c.id).\
                order_by(child.c.sortkey.desc()).\
                limit(1).\
                correlate(parent).\
                as_scalar()

mapper(Parent, parent, properties={
    'all_c':relation(Child),
    'latest_c':relation(Child, 
                            primaryjoin=and_(
                                child.c.id==latest_c, 
                                child.c.parent_id==parent.c.id
                            ),
                            uselist=False
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing .correlate()

Comment: Is it possible to do such thing using ORM models?

Comment: Why does `child.c.parent_id==parent.c.id` have to be present in both the `where` clause of `latest_c` and in the `primaryjoin`? Isn't that redundant?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of [@zzzeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931299/5320906) that uses declarative rather than imperative mapping, using [declared_attr](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.declared_attr) to insert the relationship into the parent's `__mapper_args__`.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sortkey = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    parent = orm.relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = orm.relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')

    @orm.declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        children = Child.__table__
        most_recent_child = (
            sa.select(children.c.id)
            .where(children.c.parent_id == cls.id)
            .order_by(children.c.sortkey.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .correlate(cls.__table__)
            .scalar_subquery()
        )

        rel = orm.relation(
            Child,
            primaryjoin=sa.and_(
                Child.id == most_recent_child, Child.parent_id == cls.id
            ),
            uselist=False,
            viewonly=True,
        )
        return {'properties': {'latest_child': rel}}


# Build and test.
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True, future=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

with Session.begin() as s:
    children = [Child(sortkey=i) for i in range(1, 6)]
    parent = Parent(children=children)
    s.add(parent)

with Session() as s:
    w = s.scalars(sa.select(Parent)).first()
    assert w.latest_child.sortkey == 5, f'{w.latest_child.sortkey=}'
    assert len(w.children) == 5, f'{len(w.children)=}'
```

Comment: Nice update to Mike's original answer. `orm.relation()` has been removed in 2.0, but using `orm.relationship()` instead seems to work fine.

Comment: @GordThompson what if in the  above case i have a circular reference between a parent and child?