# Using Declarative syntax, how do I define a relationship representing the latest object in a many-to-one collection?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy's declarative syntax and I'd like to specify a relationship that provides the latest (max primary id) element in a collection. I've found this post: [How do I define a SQLAlchemy relation representing the latest object in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930864/how-do-i-define-a-sqlalchemy-relation-representing-the-latest-object-in-a-collect) but I'm having a tough time using this pattern, creating a subquery using Declarative only. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated!

General Idea:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, metadata=metadata)

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

class NewsPaper(Base):
    __tablename__ = "newspapers"
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    latest_article = relationship("Article",
                                primaryjoin="(Article.newspaper_id==NewsPaper.id) &"
                                               "(Article.id==SUBQUERY_FOR_LATEST_ID)")
    def __repr__(self):
        return '''<name={0}>'''.format(self.name)


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = "articles"
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    newspaper_id =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('newspapers.id'))
    newspaper = relationship("NewsPaper", backref=backref('articles') )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '''<title={0}>'''.format(self.title)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to **define the relationship outside** the class once all classes are defined.
Remove your definition of `latest_article` from `NewsPaper` and add following code after the `class Article` definition (taken directly from Mike's answer you linked to):

```
# define the relationship
t_article = Article.__table__
t_newpaper = NewsPaper.__table__
latest_c = (select([t_article.c.id]).
            where(t_article.c.newspaper_id == t_newpaper.c.id).
            order_by(t_article.c.id.desc()).
            limit(1).
            correlate(t_newpaper).
            as_scalar()
            )
NewsPaper.latest_article = relationship("Article", 
                            primaryjoin=and_(
                                t_article.c.id==latest_c,
                                t_article.c.newspaper_id==t_newpaper.c.id,
                            ),
                            uselist=False
                           )
```

**One note though:** the relationship is working directly on the database, and as such it will not include those `Article` instances which are not yet commited but are part of the session. And most probably they would be the ones that you really want. So just be careful with that.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a fairly large project so putting the relationships after all models have been defined is a little impractical. One of the reasons I'm using Declarative is so that all of the logic for the model/mapper can live in one place. I could do it this way but it will get harder to maintain since part of the model definition will live in a fairly disconnected place.

Comment: it is enough to put it after only those two models are defined, so it would not be so disconnected.

Comment: I guess it depends on how many models and how they're laid out. I have a project structure with models defined in multiple modules that can potentially reference each other. To guarantee this pattern I'd have to add yet another module that loads after all of my model modules load creating another resource I have to track and keep in sync with the models themselves. That's why I was hoping for a solution that can be done within Declarative syntax (using string representations pre-mapper compilation etc...)

Comment: No, you don't need to add another module. If you have `Article` and `NewsPaper` defined in separate modules, you code clearly shows that module which defines `Article` imports the one which defines `NewsPaper`. So you can just put the code after you defined `Article`.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey Van, thanks again. The code above is really just an illustrative example and isn't really what the codebase looks like. You're right, though, I had a typo in my example, it's supposed to use the quoted-string relationship syntax for NewsPaper (The one that allows you to define relationships before the related models are defined). Fixed! I'm guessing there just may not be a way to do it with declarative only.