# How to construct a SQLAlchemy relationship that takes the record most recently inserted?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Imagine I've got the following:

```
class User:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    password_hash = Column(String(HASH_LENGTH), nullable=False)


class LoginAttempts:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    attempted_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Now, I want to add a relationship to `User` called `last_attempt` that retrieves the most recent login attempt. How might one do this?

Comment: Related, but a lot of water has flown since: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930864/how-do-i-define-a-sqlalchemy-relation-representing-the-latest-object-in-a-collec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a use case for [a relationship to an aliased class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#relationship-to-aliased-class), which was added in SQLAlchemy 1.3 – before that you'd use a [non primary mapper](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#multiple-mappers-for-one-class), or other methods such as a [custom primary join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930864/how-do-i-define-a-sqlalchemy-relation-representing-the-latest-object-in-a-collec). The idea is to create a subquery representing a derived table of latest login attempts per user that is then aliased to `LoginAttempts` and used as the target of a relationship. The exact query used to derive the latest attempts depends on your DBMS<sup>1</sup>, but a generic left join "antijoin" will work in most. Start by generating the (sub)query for latest login attempts:

```
newer_attempts = aliased(LoginAttempts)

# This reads as "find login attempts for which no newer attempt with larger
# attempted_at exists". The same could be achieved using NOT EXISTS as well.
latest_login_attempts_query = select([LoginAttempts]).\
    select_from(
        outerjoin(LoginAttempts, newer_attempts,
                  and_(newer_attempts.user_id == LoginAttempts.user_id,
                       newer_attempts.attempted_at > LoginAttempts.attempted_at))).\
    where(newer_attempts.id == None).\
    alias()

latest_login_attempts = aliased(LoginAttempts, latest_login_attempts_query)
```

Then just add the relationship attribute to your `User` model:

```
User.last_attempt = relationship(latest_login_attempts, uselist=False,
                                 viewonly=True)
```

---

<sup>1: For example in Postgresql you could replace the LEFT JOIN subquery with a LATERAL subquery, NOT EXISTS, a query using window functions, or `SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) ... ORDER BY (user_id, attempted_at DESC)`.</sup>

Comment: Whats the implication of having a session created during model definition? Don't we want that query to be generated as needed, specific to the model instance?

Comment: Good point and instead of writing the subquery as an ORM query I should've used Core, will update. The statement does not need to be instance specific. Any DBMS worth its salt will push the predicates and otherwise optimize the query if needed.

Comment: But, as noted, different DBMS offer different tools for handling the "latest" query and they will probably offer different performance depending on your data. In Postgresql you could for example user a lateral subquery or the `DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY` query.

Comment: Yeah, lots of options, thanks for the update! One last question: anyway to make this `backref` friendly?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Thinking about it, how would SQLAlchemy know when loading `LoginAttempts` that this is the latest login attempt of the related user? In fact `last_attempt` should probably be defined as `viewonly=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the selected answer is more robust, another way you could accomplish this is to use a `lazy=dynamic` and `order_by`:

```
User.last_attempted = relationship(LoginAttempts, order_by=desc(LoginAttempts.attempted_at), lazy='dynamic')
```

Be careful though, because this returns a query object (and will require `.first()` or equivalent), and you will need to use a limit clause:

```
last_attempted_login = session.query(User).get(my_user_id).last_attempted.limit(1).first()
```

Comment: Minor note: there's no need to put `limit(1)` because "first() applies a limit of one within the generated SQL" (docs)